# Image not being displayed in button

Tags: java, image, button, awt

I am trying to add an image with some text to an awt button.  The program adds the image name passed to the constructor and the appropriate paint methods are performed. But when the button is displayed, it does not contain the image or the text.

Here's the code

```
        public ImageButton1(String imageName, String text, Enum position) {
    super();
    theImage = tk.getImage(imageName);
    this.text = text;
    this.position = position;
    MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
    tracker.addImage(theImage, 0);
    try {
        tracker.waitForAll();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading image -" + e.getMessage().toString());
    }

    imgWidth = theImage.getWidth(this);
    imgHeight = theImage.getHeight(this);
    width = imgWidth + 6;
    height = imgHeight + 6;

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    switch (position.ordinal()) {
        case 0: {
            g.drawString(text, height - imgHeight, height - imgHeight);
            g.drawImage(theImage, 3, 3, getSize().width - 6,
                    getSize().height - 6, this);
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            g.drawImage(theImage, 3, 3, getSize().width - 6,
                    getSize().height - 6, this);
            g.drawString(text, height - imgHeight, height - imgHeight);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            g.drawString(text, width - imgWidth, width - imgWidth);
            g.drawImage(theImage, 3, 3, getSize().width - 6,
                    getSize().height - 6, this);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            g.drawImage(theImage, 3, 3, getSize().width - 6,
                    getSize().height - 6, this);
            g.drawString(text, width - imgWidth, width - imgWidth);
            break;
        }
        default:
            g.drawString(text, width - imgWidth, width - imgWidth);
            break;
    }
}
```

After running the debugger, I noticed that the imgWidth and imgHeight values are -1.  The image is being referenced in the watched button.

Comment: I have used the enum ordinal method in the switch statement because the case statements would not recognize the enum literals

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre]

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. One reason not mentioned there (AFAIR) is that the Swing `JButton` is already able to display an `ImageIcon`.

Comment: I am working out of an old book. Except for the paint method changes, the code is as it appears in the book.  Will look into swing after I finish the book.

Comment: *"I am working out of an old book."* I'd use the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) (free & **up to date** - which AWT components have not been for 15+ years now). BTW - Tip: Add @Frakcool (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.